# How to extend colorbar for 'out-of-range' values in Bokeh or Holoview?

Tags: matplotlib, bokeh, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

In Matplotlib, there is the colorbar property [`extend`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) that makes pointed end(s) for out-of- range values. How would you do the third subplots with Bokeh or Holoview?

I added a [Matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/colorbar_basics.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-colorbar-basics-py) below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# setup some generic data
N = 37
x, y = np.mgrid[:N, :N]
Z = (np.cos(x*0.2) + np.sin(y*0.3))

# mask out the negative and positive values, respectively
Zpos = np.ma.masked_less(Z, 0)
Zneg = np.ma.masked_greater(Z, 0)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 3), ncols=3)

# plot just the positive data and save the
# color "mappable" object returned by ax1.imshow
pos = ax1.imshow(Zpos, cmap='Blues', interpolation='none')

# add the colorbar using the figure's method,
# telling which mappable we're talking about and
# which axes object it should be near
fig.colorbar(pos, ax=ax1)

# repeat everything above for the negative data
neg = ax2.imshow(Zneg, cmap='Reds_r', interpolation='none')
fig.colorbar(neg, ax=ax2)

# Plot both positive and negative values between +/- 1.2
pos_neg_clipped = ax3.imshow(Z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=-1.2, vmax=1.2,
                             interpolation='none')
# Add minorticks on the colorbar to make it easy to read the
# values off the colorbar.
cbar = fig.colorbar(pos_neg_clipped, ax=ax3, extend='both')
cbar.minorticks_on()
plt.show()
```

**Example plot, colorbar with pointed ends to point out higher values:**

[image: example plot pointed ends colorbar]

Answer (score 2):

Bokeh has a current PR (not finished) to try to add functionality like this: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/10781